# Assign shortcut for "Look Up" in context menu

Tags: macos, keyboard, shortcut, shortcut-menu, contextual-menu

I'm looking for a way to assign a shortcut for the right click button *Look Up*. So that I can just select some text and call that without using the mouse. Below is the pop-up that shows up when you look something up.

I'm aware of the *"Look Up in Dictionary"* service and ability to assign a shortcut for that but it's not the same.

[image: Look Up Pop Up]

Answer (score 1):

You could try adding the keyboard shortcut for "Look Up in Dictionary"

[image]

Once you have that set, you can add a dictation command (assuming you have advanced dictation enabled) by just selecting any text and speak the phrase "make this speakable" which will open this dialog box..

[image]

Use what ever phrase you want, then select keyboard shortcut in the drop-down menu and enter in the same shortcut you set in your system preferences.  Now you have a keyboard shortcut and a dictation command